# Array of Arrays?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

So here is my scenario -- I am collecting a dynamic folder structure with javascript for a photoshop plugin I am developing. Here is what the folders may look like:

```
Folder 1
    subFolder1
        file1
        file2
    subFolder2
        subsubfolder1
        subsubfolder2
           file1
           file2


 Folder 2
        subFolder1
            file1
            file2
        subFolder2
            subsubfolder1
            subsubfolder2
               file1
               file2
```

What would this syntax look like? tried to come up with it, but doesn't look right to me. Also how would you loop through something like that? Do you for look on every sub array?

```
var multiArray = [ [Folder1, [subFolder1, [file1,file2],subFolder2, [subsubFolder1, subsubFolder2, [file1,file2] ], Folder2, [subFolder1, [file1,file2], subFolder2, [subsubfolder1,subsubfoler2, [file1,file2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var who = {
   just: "an object",
   with: "a couple of properties"
};

var ArrayOofArrays = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,7],
    [1,{},""],
    ["a",2,{c: "b",e: who}]
];
```

In your example:

```
var folder = {
    subfolders: [
        subfolder,
        subfolder
    ],
    files: [
        file,
        file
    ]
};
```

subfolder would be ->

```
var subfolder = function () {
    return {
        folders: [
        ],
        files: [
        ],
        path: "path/to/folder" // etc..
    }
};
```

file would be ->

```
var fileInfo = function () {
    return {
        filename: "path/to/file" // etc.
    };
}
```

it really depends on what you want to achieve, but generally a combination of objects and arrays is best.

so you could have something like

```
var buildFolder = function(){
    return {
        folders: [],
        files: []
    };
};

var buildFile = function(title){
    return {
        title: title
    };
};

var folder = buildFolder();

folder.files.push(buildFile());
folder.files.push(buildFile());
folder.files.push(buildFile());
folder.files.push(buildFile());

folder.folders.push(buildFolder());
folder.folders[0].files.push(buildFile());
```

Comment: sorry man, your much better at this than I, can you help me translate that. Thanks